# How do i add reg exp to sed?

Tags: awk, sed

```
action: 'blah' 'blah'
```

Need to remove anything that is after `action:` in a file

```
sed -i 's/action:\*//g' tes1
```

This does not do anything.

Comment: wrt `anything that is after action: in a file` - do you mean anything that is after it on each line, or anything after the first occurrence of it in the file or something else? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: If you have Bash compare  `<<<'xy*z' sed 's/y\*/'` with `<<<'xy*z' sed 's/y*/'` with `<<<'xy*z' sed 's/y*/g'` with `<<<'xy*z' sed 's/y.*/'`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are confusing *globbing* with *regular expressions*. In your question you have:

> Need to remove anything that is after action: in a file
>
> ```
> sed -i 's/action:\*//g' tes1
> ```
>
> This does not do anything.

Of course it doesn't if the input is `"action: 'blah' 'blah'"`. The only thing that would be matched by your attempt would be a literal:

```
action:*
```

(the *glob*, e.g. wildcard, `'*'` matches any number of characters as a shell expression, not a *regular expression*. As a regular expression, it controls repetition)

What you want to do is match the `"action:"` portion and then match everything that follows it, replacing what follows with nothing. The general match any number of characters until end of line is `.*$` Where `'.'` matches any character, the repetition `'*'` matches *zero-or-more* times and finally the `'$'` anchors the expression to the end of line.

Put another way, you want to match `"action:"` at the beginning of the line, followed by any number of additional characters, and you want to replace all additional characters with nothing. To anchor `action:` to the beginning of the line you use the circumflex `'^'`, e.g. `"^action:"` to ensure you only match `"action:"` and not `"any action:"`.

Putting it altogether, you could use:

```
sed -i 's/^action:.*$/action:/' tes1
```

Which in sum matches `"action: and to end of line"` and replaces the entire expression with `"action:"` leaving you with your desired line containing only `"action:"`.